# Android Studio KotLin Insert/Update/Delete in Postgresql

Tags: android, postgresql, android-studio, kotlin

good day, I just want to ask that do you have any documentation (step by step) on how to Insert/Update/Delete in Android Studio using kotlin and postgresql for the database? I am new in android studio.  I cant find any documentation I need for inserting/updating or deleting data in android studio using kotlin and postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use any library like [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) where I assume you have postgresql as API endpoint, so simply you can go by the Retrofit documentation or many youtube tutorials, blogs
(https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html or 
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial/) which have described it. But first of all you need to have your API endpoint via which your android app can communicate with postgresql database

Comment: I am new in android studio, is this easy to understand right?

Comment: is it okay to use php to connect in postgresql?

Comment: You need to know basics of Android, then it would be easier, but you can learn step by step ,ya but you need to have an API endpoint to communicate with the app

Comment: Thats completely your choice which language you wanna use, it was just an exmple, many more languages are there

Comment: thanks pal. i will wait 5 mins more to accept your answer